# dotnet new install from github package

Tags: nuget, dotnet-cli

How to install template "dotnet new install" from public package on github?

I have add source

```
dotnet nuget add source --username USER --password TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/USER/index.json"
```

I have publish package

```
dotnet nuget push "bin/Debug/PACKAGE-NAME.1.0.0.nupkg"  --api-key TOKEN --source "github"
```

I have change visibility to public

I have try to install

```
dotnet new install PACKAGE-NAME --nuget-source https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/pkgs/nuget/PACKAGE-NAME --force -v diag
```

```
[2023-04-27 22:08:40.667] [Debug] [NuGetLogger] => [Execute]: Details: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: 
Failed to fetch results from V2 feed at 'https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY/pkgs/nuget/PACKAGE-NAME/FindPackagesById()?id='PACKAGE-NAME'&semVerLevel=2.0.0' 
with following message : 
Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable).
```